# Coarse-grained algorithms

Tags: computational-chemistry

I am fairly new to the field of oarse-grained molecular systems. I am aware that there are a lot of different already developed CG algorithms. Since there are so many, I struggle to find what I'm looking for.
I wonder if there is a CG algorithms that simplifies a molecule drastically, for example a method that describes a mAb with around 20k atoms with only 12 or 20 beads while not assuming the number of beads beforehand, but rather choosing a partitioning that is most favorable according to a certain metric. Is any such method developed and also open-source?

Comment: You are probably better off asking this on the [Matter modelling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) forum

Comment: BTW I would spell out CG as "Coarse Grained" - I automatically read it as "Conjugate Gradient" and there may be other confusions.

Comment: "partitioning that is most favorable": It depends what property of the antibody you want to model. You might be interested in antigene binding, aggregation, conformational change, transport properties, - you name it. Without knowing what you want the model to do for you, it is impossible to evaluate the model or come up with a metric.